# Bootstrap collapse mobile navbar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Meteor project, and my navigation bar is supposed to have the collapsing functionality that Bootstrap provides.   The following is my navigation code:

```
<!-- Navigation, via bootstrap -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <section class="container-fluid">

        <section class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ pathFor 'home' }}"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;AccountedFor</a>
        </section>

        <!-- collapse? -->
        <section class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {{#if currentUser}}
                    <p class="navbar-text">|</p>
                    <li><a href="{{pathFor 'categories'}}">Manage Categories</a></li>
                {{/if}}
                <p class="navbar-text">|</p>
                <li><a href="{{pathFor 'about'}}">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <section class="navbar-right">
                <p class="navbar-text">
                    {{> loginButtons align="right"}}
                </p>
            </section>

        </section> <!-- end collapse -->
    </section>
</nav>
```

This is what the current bar looks like, after I clicked the button that should be expanding the menu.

[image: Incorrect Navbar]

This is what the bar looks like when it is of adequate width to not require collapse, with all entries visible:

[image: Full Navbar]

It has no problem showing the applicable toggle button when the size of the window is appropriate, but the collapsing functionality I'm expecting does not happen.  Anyone care to offer some advice?  Thanks ahead of time:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfo38kb1/ <-- This fiddle illustrates the problem I'm having.

Comment: mind putting it in a fiddle or something?

Comment: I can try that momentarily.  I will probably have to modify it to work in a fiddle as this is part of a Meteor application and some of the stuff won't work without the app present.

Comment: Understandable, but it's hard to tell what could be causing your issue without seeing a bit more.

Comment: Are you sure you included the bootstrap.js on your page? Happened to me once.

Comment: Fiddle added per request, link in original question.

Comment: bootstrap.js file is missing in your fiddle.   
Including it makes it working. see this 

http://jsfiddle.net/bfo38kb1/1/

Comment: Oh.  I just realized that I'm not using a package to provide Bootstrap, but manual inclusion via <head> tag.   If you wouldn't care to toss that mention of Bootstrap.JS in an answer, I will gladly accept it as correct.  What a silly oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap.js file is missing in your fiddle.
Including it makes it working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

see this 
http://jsfiddle.net/bfo38kb1/1